# WordPress post permalinks for multiple categories, tags and taxonomy terms

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, custom-taxonomy

I'm creating a WordPress plugin and one of the requirements is that a custom post type (photo) with a custom taxonomy (photos) needs to generate multiple permalinks if the post is assigned to multiple terms... so for example if a post is assigned to two taxonomy terms ("birthday" and "wedding") both of the following permalinks should display the post:

```
/photos/bithday/photo/post-name

/photos/wedding/photo/post-name
```

I currently have the following rewrite rule defined, which is returning a 404:

```
add_rewrite_rule( 'photos/(.*)/photo/(.*)?', 'index.php?post_type=photo&taxonomy=photos&term=$matches[1]&pagename=$matches[2]', 'top' );
```

However, if I visit the following URL which matches the pattern of my rewrite rule:

```
/index.php?post_type=photo&taxonomy=photos&term=birthday&pagename=post-name
```

It returns the correct content, but only after redirecting to this URL:

```
/photo/post-name/?taxonomy=photos&term=birthday-cakes
```

I must be missing something, any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: I've seen some suggestions to use the Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer plugin to test my rewrite rule, which I did and it shows that my rewrite rule should be working...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this working by changing &pagename= to &name=.